# there is nothing in network tab when i was browsering or refershing any web page

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend

there is nothing in network tab when i was browsering or refershing any web page. filter iocon showing red and it is not working. there is no data in network pannel. Chrome inspector does not show network requests path and etc.
filter iocon showing red and it is not working. nothing happning when i was clicking on filter icon it remain red.

Before clicking on filter icon
[image]

After clicking on filter icon

[image: After clicking on filter icon]

there is no data, why??

Comment: Press the filter button. That’s the red funnel shape.

Comment: Yes, of course the filter button is red. Why would you expect it to change color? Why do you think the color is relevant right now? What do you see when you click it? There’s a list of events that can be filtered. What do they look like? What happens when you click those?

Comment: filter iocon showing red and it is not working. nothing happning when i was clicking on filter icon it remain red.

Comment: Click on the [filter options](//i.stack.imgur.com/3mINn.png)…

Comment: You have “player” typed into the search field. What happens if you clear this search field?

Comment: Sebastian Simon
  thank you. it was comming by default.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost certainly filtering by string or request type, but you've hidden the filter menu so that isn't obvious. Click the filter icon (third icon from the left, just under the E of Elements) and disable your filtering.

Comment: filter icon not working sir . what can i do??

Comment: @DeepakGauttam [What Do You Mean “It Doesn’t Work”?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616/289905)

Comment: filter iocon showing red and it is not working. nothing happning when i was clicking on filter icon it remain red.

Comment: It's supposed to remain red until the remove the filters. Is nothing really happening or are you just not noticing the filter menu bar that is added to the UI?

Comment: can we do meeting over google meet i can show you. please help me. nothing happning when i was clinking on filter icon.